# potentiometric position sensor

Tags: sensor, position

I would like to wire my position sensor ([Datasheet](http://www.novotechnik.de/uploads/tx_extprodfind/T_TS_e.pdf)) into Arduino. I plan to connect it with Arduino 5V supply and then read analog input values. It is potentiometric sensor and has 3 wires.

After looking at datasheet there are many values for current in uA range, like Recommended operating wiper current (<1uA)??. Can somebody take a look at datasheet and check if I understand it right... Is it normal? ..If, yes, how to wire it to acheave such a low current with 0-5V proportional output signal. Have somebody experience with such a sensors.

I just dont want to burn it...:)

Comment: What resistance is the pot?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real problem unless you have a big malfunction... The max allowable current is 10 mA, so you have to stay below that. Simple - put a 500 Ohm (well, 470) in series with the potmeter 'arm' if you are working at 5V. That won't change the measurement and protects your potentiometer.

The uA values are so that the load of the measurement won't influence the linearity of the potentiometer, and ruin the precision while measuring.

The linear potentiometer is just a wirewound resistor, so it's fairly robust.